# AWS, VPC with Public and Private Subnets, outgoing security group settings query

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm following this [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html#VPC_Scenario2_Implementation) which suggests to set up a security group for the NAT, the databases, and the webservers.

In terms of security groups, the doc specifies to only allow outgoing traffic for the web instance to the databases and incoming http and https.

I'm struggling to understand how the webserver can respond to requests if outgoing on http and https are blocked by this setting.

Have I misunderstood something here, or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security groups are statefull, meaning that the connections that you allow in are automatically allowed out. Also, security groups are only permissive, they only deny what is not explicitly allowed. Because of that, you usually do not need to explicitly allow outbound rules.

But if you need to allow outbound traffic without being related to an inbound connection, then explicit outbound rules are helpful.